# UITableView and Cells from Model Array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I'm stuck on something I don't quite understand as from a few tests, it looks like the generation of table cell is happening before but not as well after a page load and Alamofire request.

If you see below I'm trying to get it to where our museum's outbound shipments are viewed after referencing the pro:

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ShipmentProSearchResultsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var pronumber:String = ""
    var shipments = [Shipment]()
    typealias JSONStandard = [String: AnyObject]

    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchShipments()

    }

    func fetchShipments() {
        let parameters: Parameters = ["pro_number": pronumber]
        let todoEndpoint: String = "OURHOST/shipments/api/details/pro"
        Alamofire.request(todoEndpoint, method: .get, parameters: parameters)
            .responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess{
                let shipmentJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                for (index, subJson):(String, JSON) in shipmentJSON{
                    let proNumber = subJson["proNumber"].int
                    let consigneeName = subJson["consignee"]["name"].string
                    let shipment = Shipment(proNumber: proNumber!, consigneeName: consigneeName!)

                    self.shipments.append(shipment)
                }
                print(self.shipments)
            }else{
                print("Could not get results")
            }
        }
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return shipments.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShipmentCell", for: indexPath)
        let shipment = shipments[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(shipment.proNumber)"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Now where I printed the `self.shipments`, I get the following results:

```
[OakRidgeArchaeologicalRepositoryDispatcher.Shipment(proNumber: 471008276, consigneeName: "A1 CHICAGO INSTITUTE OF THE ARTS")]
```

So I know the data is appropriately being passed to the model. I will also note that the Table View Cell Identifier in the storyboard is correctly set to `ShipmentCell`. But after the query, nothing pops up in my table.

I'm using Swift 4.

Answer (score 0):

You should reload the `tableView` after updating source field.

```
func fetchShipments() {
        let parameters: Parameters = ["pro_number": pronumber]
        let todoEndpoint: String = "OURHOST/shipments/api/details/pro"
        Alamofire.request(todoEndpoint, method: .get, parameters: parameters)
            .responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess{
                let shipmentJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                for (index, subJson):(String, JSON) in shipmentJSON{
                    let proNumber = subJson["proNumber"].int
                    let consigneeName = subJson["consignee"]["name"].string
                    let shipment = Shipment(proNumber: proNumber!, consigneeName: consigneeName!)

                    self.shipments.append(shipment)
                }
                tableView.reloadData() //<-------add this.
                print(self.shipments)
            }else{
                print("Could not get results")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is right the tableView needs to be reload. However it has to happen on main thread. So wrap @ocanal 's suggestion inside `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reload }`